# "attempt to free a non-heap object" in C

Tags: c, memory

#### Sample code

I've written code somewhat like the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct record {
  ...
};

void record_cleanup(struct record *record)
{
  printf("Deleting record %p\n", record);
  free(record);
}

int main(void)
{
  struct record record;
  ...
  record_cleanup(&record);
  ...
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

#### Error

However, upon compiling, I received an error:

```
warning: attempt to free a non-heap object
```

What is causing this, and why?

Comment: `record instance = malloc(sizeof(record));` how is this correct?

Comment: The whole snippet is very confusing!

Comment: @SouravGhosh As a relatively new stack overflow user who is still learning the trade, I try to make my questions and answers as thorough as possible... Please be more specific on what you're confused about. About your first comment, that is getting the size of `record`, and making a `malloc` call in order to allocate memory for that structure. I have made edits to my question, as `malloc` returns a `void*` and must be cast to a pointer type.

Comment: that little `*` makes a lot of difference, you know!

Comment: @Sourav And what about your second comment?

Comment: The variable `instance`, whether assigned a value received from a parameter which has a corresponding argument which is allocated memory is complete irrelevant in this case. The point is, `instance` is an automatic local scoped variable, and `&instance` is not allocated memory. The type of variable and it's value assignment is confusing, as they are not really relevant / related in this case.

Comment: @Sourav When the record is passed to `function()` as a `void*`, it's cast to its initial `record` type, which attempts to free it. This is invalid since the local variable `instance` isn't in heap memory and thus cannot be freed. If there is _any_ unclarity in my code, please leave a comment so I can edit my post, rather than downvoting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is coming from `free(record)`

In `record_cleanup`:

> ```c
> free(record);
> ```

In `main`:

> ```c
> struct record record; /* stack-allocation; cannot be free()ed */
> ...
> record_cleanup(&record); /* calls free(record), which isn't allowed */
> ```